# Outputs from exec() in windows (PHP)?

Tags: php, exec

not seem to getting the outputs from exec() command in PHP, OS: Windows XP

here's the code used:
exec("echo %username%",$output);

using print_r($output) which returns 1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is not a program on Windows that you can call. It is a feature provided specifically by the command processor (i.e. `cmd.exe`).

If you want the username in this manner don't start up a shell. Use [`getenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) instead.

(If for some reason you wanted to use `echo` you would need to do `cmd.exe /c echo Whatever`. Also note that checking the return code as well as the output may be useful)